# Stop a Javascript countdown

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a pomodoro clock, everthing is working well but when the user clicks to run the the counter more than once I get two counters working I would like to pause the counter and not start another.

```
function countdown(minutes) {
  let seconds = 60;
  let mins = minutes;
  function tick() {
    let current_minutes = mins-1;
    seconds--;
    time.innerHTML = current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
    if( seconds > 0 ) {
      setTimeout(tick, 1000);
      } else {
      if(mins > 1){
          countdown(mins-1);         
      }
     }

    console.log(mins);

    if (seconds === 0 && mins === 1) {
      time.innerHTML = `${sessionLength}:00`;
      rounds++;
      console.log(rounds);
      PlaySound(sound);
    }
  }
tick();
}
```

how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Make a variable "counterIsRunning", and wrap your logic in a "counterIsRunning === false" condition

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use setInterval?

```
var myPomodoro = setInterval(function(){
   //... run code in here every 60 seconds
}, 60000);

// stop the timer
clearInterval(myPomodoro);
```